# Maven dependency plugin

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a top level pom with nested projects and subdirectories. When I invoke 'mvn dependency : tree' on my top level pom to get the list of dependencies for all child projects, I got none. The result is

"The following files have been resolved: none".

Kindly let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the command line output?

Comment: I hope you did not type the spaces before and after the : in your command (you need to write `mvn dependency:tree`.

Answer (score 0):

the command is correct

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

your tree directory must look like

```
/project-parent/pom.xml
/project-parent/module-a/pom.xml
/project-parent/module-b/pom.xml
```

and your parent pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <name>Project-parent</name>

  <groupId>com.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>   
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <description>Project Parent</description>

   . . . properties, etc

  <modules>
        <module>module-a</module>
        <module>module-b</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Comment: Yes, am having exactly like this. Only difference is, am having profiles in my pom.